# Hyper-V replica - PowerShell - replica merge (detect / invoke)

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, powershell-v3.0

I need a PowerShell command which can detect replica merge process on the specific VM. And to be sure... There is no way how to invoke replica merge process using a PowerShell command.. Am I right?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There is (atleast with Hyper-V 2012 ) please have a look here http://blogs.technet.com/b/matthts/archive/2012/04/02/managing-hyper-v-replica-from-powershell.aspx , you can find a lot more if you go over 70-411 / 70-412 courses or maybe the "private cloud " MCSE from Microsoft .

Comment: Thanks, but there isn't what I need. I checked all Hyper-V Cmdlets [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx), but I can't find any command for detection or invoking Hyper-V replica merge process.

Comment: Hmm you might need http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848594.aspx Measure-VMReplication and you can browse all the list of the current powershell commandlets via http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848594.aspx .

Comment: I browsed all the Hyper-V cmdlets and I'm using Measure-VMReplication cmdlet, but this cmdlet doesn't provide functionality what I'm looking for. Maybe under the "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMCurrentTask]" can be listed merge task, but I don't know how to view this list relating to the specific VM...

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you are trying to see which VM is replicating to where ?

Comment: No, I know how to check this. I need a way how to check if the replica merge process is running (possibly the way how to invoke this process). Merge process is performed on the replica server (changes from the primary server are transmited to the replica server and merged into the avhdx file(s)).

Comment: Then it might be quite simple you can use Get-Process http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855.aspx you can even check it remotely from a single server

Comment: I know this cmdlet, but the process I need to identify isn't separate process which can be shown for example in the task manager. I give up. I'll find another way how to solve my problem. Anyway... THANK YOU

Comment: With pleasure , unfortunately my knowledge is limited there at the moment .Good luck!